# What is the other name of a triangular prism? (sound like "retch")

Tags: word-usage

As an ELL, I heard my boss said "retch" a few times. (Note: "retch" is just what I think how the word is spelled). My boss was talking about a triangular prism. What is the correct word? Thanks

Comment: How was it used and in what sentence? What does it look like? [Details please.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Answer (score 11):

I kept guessing it for a while. I think I figured it out!

I think the word is **wedge**.

> **[wedge](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wedge)**  /wedʒ/
>   <sup>NOUN [COUNTABLE]</sup>
>   1. a piece of wood, plastic, or other material that is thin at one end and wider at the other and is pressed into a space to hold something in place or to force things apart

[image]

As a bonus, I also guess that your boss was probably talking about this :-)

[image]