# A triangular prism? What else its shape could be?

Tags: word-choice

Looking at [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20955/what-is-the-other-name-of-a-triangular-prism-sound-like-retch), first, I thought for a while about redundancy. A **triangular prism**. I searched on Wikipedia for the terms [prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism) that says *At least two of the flat surfaces must have an angle between them. (means triangle, isn't it?* and [triangular prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism) that says *a three-sided prism.*

In addition, I searched Google Images with triangle prism and prism. Most of them were triangle!

Of course, the latter one talks about *geometry* but still, *a triangular prism?* Why simply not say *prism* and it includes its shape i.e. triangle! Fun is, I searched for *round prism* and *rectangle prism* - both have results! Google is great!

Comment: "**At least** two of the flat surfaces..."

Comment: @helix true but what else shape you can come up for being a prism?

Comment: I can conceive of a trapezoidal prism, though I have no idea of its practical application

Comment: @MaulikV [lots](http://www.ditutor.com/solid_gometry/types_prisms.html)

Comment: @helix did you check the Wiki page for *prism?* What shape an ideal prism has is shown there. And the question came to my mind **after** searching on Wikipedia and Google images.

Comment: A cylinder is a prism. So are [these](http://www.northstarmath.com/sitemap/images/clip_image001_058.gif). Why say "triangular prism"? Because a prism isn't necessarily triangular. A prism's base can have any shape or number of sides.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, yes. it's clear now. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are [lots of other kinds](http://www.ditutor.com/solid_gometry/types_prisms.html), people often use the word *prism* to refer to a *triangular prism*.

> <sub>[From the same Wikipedia article you linked...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism)</sub>
>
> The **traditional** geometrical shape is that of a triangular prism with a
> triangular base and rectangular sides, and in **colloquial** use "prism"
> usually refers to this type.

> <sub>[From Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prism)</sub>
>
> A transparent block in the shape of a prism (**typically with triangular
> ends**), used to split or reflect light.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was a bit confused about!

Answer (score 2):

In a *single lense reflex* (SLR) photo camera, you often have a [*pentaprism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaprism) to transfer the immage that is seen through the lens, and reflected from the mirror before the shutter to the *ocular* (eyepiece).

[image: pentaprism]

If you look at the shape, you will see it fits your definition, and yet, it is not triangular :)

Comment: Thank you. True..it has to be specified to mean a triangular prism. +1 :)

Comment: I have to admit that before I started photography, I had _no_ idea about this either :)